# Trouble Using Edit Search Function in Recycler View with Cards

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-search

I am trying to search through a recycler view with cards by allowing a user to search. When the user searches, the cards should "reorganize" to show according to the characters entered by the user. I have tried to do this but am having issues doing this. Any assistance is appreciated.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), BottomSheetRecyclerViewAdapter.ListTappedListener {
    private var customAdapter: CustomAdapter? = null
    private var arrayListModel = ArrayList<Model>()
    private lateinit var bottomSheetBehavior: CustomBottomSheetBehavior<ConstraintLayout>
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val modelList = readFromAsset()
        val adapterList = CustomAdapter(modelList, this)
        customAdapter = CustomAdapter(arrayListModel, this@MainActivity)

        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetLayout) as CustomBottomSheetBehavior

        recyclerView.adapter = adapterList
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)

        et_search.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                if (!s.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    val searchList = ArrayList<Model>()
                    for (i in arrayListModel.indices) {
                        if (arrayListModel[i].name.toLowerCase().contains(s)) {
                            searchList.add(arrayListModel[i])
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        customAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        recyclerView.adapter = CustomAdapter(searchList, this@MainActivity)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                } else {
                    customAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    recyclerView.adapter = customAdapter
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onClickList(text: String) {
    }

    private fun readFromAsset(): List<Model> {

        val modeList = mutableListOf<Model>()
        val bufferReader = application.assets.open("android_version.json").bufferedReader()
        val json_string = bufferReader.use {
            it.readText()
        }

        val jsonArray = JSONArray(json_string);
        for (i in 0..jsonArray.length() - 1) {
            val jsonObject: JSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
            val model = Model(jsonObject.getString("name"), jsonObject.getString("version"))
            modeList.add(model)
        }
        return modeList
    }
}
```

Comment: code looks fine . when  and where you are getting problem ?

Comment: thanks for the response-When I search, nothing shows up. For example, my cards contain things like "Store" so when I type in "s", cards with "s" such as "Store" should show up but no cards are showing.

Comment: replace this `arrayListModel[i].name.contains(s,true) ` and  also add this line `if` condition `Log.e("name",arrayListModel[i].name) .check log how many result you found.

Comment: convert CharSequence to String while comparing with name. ie, s.toString

Comment: @frankenstein I tried putting that in but still no cards come up. Nothng shows up in the log.e either.

Comment: @rengineer Print then size of `arrayListModel`  .check it contain data or not .

Comment: hmm the size doesn't come up as anything.

Comment: @frankenstein Also when I backspace to clear the search bar, all the cards don't show up. I wonder whats causing it to do this

Comment: @rengineer added my answer check that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might found your problem. Here you getting data   `val modelList = readFromAsset()` but  you are never assigning data to `arrayListModel` that your problem.

Assign the data to `arrayListModel`

```
  val modelList = readFromAsset()
  arrayListModel=modelList
```

Comment: Nice-this fixed the problem when I back space and nothing shows-now, when I back space the whole thing, the cards all show up but not when I put in something. When I type in something, no cards show up still.

Comment: I wonder if theres something where the search isn't somehow correctly connecting with the cards so thats why when i search, nothing shows up

Comment: I feel like in this portion, something isn;t working try recyclerView.adapter = CustomAdapter(searchList, this@MainActivity)

Comment: still you are not getting output on the search ?

Comment: Sorry I got it to work! Thanks for the help. The problem was arrayListModel[i].version.contains(s,true). I need the ".version". I forgot I had changed that previously

Comment: I appreciated the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clean approach you might want to consider/try:
Make your adapter implement the filterable interface. 
Provide your own Filter object in which you implement your filtering logic (asynch).
You might as well use a SearchView instead of using onTextChange on an EditText.

So: onTextChange(newText) => call adapter.getFilter().filter(newText) => filtering happens in background (filter method performFiltering is called) => when filtered list ready (filter method publishResults is called), you push it to your adapter and notifyDataSetChanged.

Hope this helps.
Here's a clean example on how to implement this:
[Example](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/searchview-recyclerview)